# Getting rotateTransition and pathtransition to work on a resizable window

Tags: animation, javafx

I had a bit of a problem developing a test Javafx program that deals with passing rectangle objects across the screen from different directions. In order to make this work, I  created the rectangle objects and then three line objects. I then created a PathTransition object that would have a rectangle travel along each line object. From there, I created a Pane object and added both the three rectangles and three lines on top of it.
To simulate that the rectangles were coming from different directions, I used a RotateTransition object and used the Pane object as its node. Basically, the program is just a rotating pane that carries three lines that each have a rectangle moving down the path of said line. However, when I want to resize the window, I don't know how to exactly cause the size of the pane to change with it without messing up the animations. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.animation.RotateTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Pane object
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        // Rectangle objects
        Rectangle yellowRectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        yellowRectangle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        Rectangle greenRectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        greenRectangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        Rectangle blueRectangle = new Rectangle(10,10,10,10);
        blueRectangle.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Line yellowLine = new Line(0,0,500,500);
        yellowLine.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);

        Line greenLine = new Line(500,0,0,500);
        greenLine.setStroke(Color.GREEN);

        Line blueLine = new Line(0,250,500,250);
        blueLine.setStroke(Color.BLUE);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(yellowRectangle, greenRectangle, blueRectangle, yellowLine, greenLine, blueLine);

        // Pathtransitions
        PathTransition yellowPath = new PathTransition();
        yellowPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        yellowPath.setPath(yellowLine);
        yellowPath.setNode(yellowRectangle);
        yellowPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        yellowPath.setAutoReverse(true);
        yellowPath.play();

        PathTransition greenPath = new PathTransition();
        greenPath.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        greenPath.setPath(greenLine);
        greenPath.setNode(greenRectangle);
        greenPath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        greenPath.setAutoReverse(true);
        greenPath.play();

        PathTransition bluePath = new PathTransition();
        bluePath.setDuration(Duration.millis(4000));
        bluePath.setPath(blueLine);
        bluePath.setNode(blueRectangle);
        bluePath.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        bluePath.setAutoReverse(true);
        bluePath.play();

        // Rotate Transition
        RotateTransition yellowRotate = new RotateTransition();
        yellowRotate.setAxis(Rotate.Z_AXIS);
        yellowRotate.setByAngle(360);
        yellowRotate.setCycleCount(500);
        yellowRotate.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
        yellowRotate.setAutoReverse(true);
        yellowRotate.setNode(pane);
        yellowRotate.play();

        // Borderpane
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1000, 1000);

        // Bind the BorderPane to the scene
        borderPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
        borderPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setResizable(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing the example. But I didnt get the actual question. The size of the pane is indeed changing when resizing the window. I am not clear what you are expecting for. Set pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#AAAAAA50;"); to see what is happening.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, and thanks for the line of code that allowed me to see the pane clearly. This application was supposed to be a sort of test game where you would try to click on the different rectangular objects as they moved across the screen. You score points each time you successfully click on a rectangle. But first, I just wanted to get the layout working correctly. I wanted all of the lines to be in the center of the window and the ends of the pane not to be seen so that each rectangle can move into and out of view of the screen. The lines resize when the window is resized.